# Execute Subquery once only

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

How do I execute a Subquery once in a Query like this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b149d/1/0

```
select 
id, 
(
  select group_concat(user) 
  from table_b
) as subquery 
from table_a
```

to maintain performance of the Query, Or it is better If I run two Queries separatly?

I want a result as if I used

```
select group_concat(user) from talbe_b;
select id from table_a;
```

but in a single query.

Comment: What would you like the output of your query to be?

Comment: @gareth I want to get all `users` from `table_b` to be used in a different place once, Something like if first row has the `group_concat` and all rows after it is about the `id`

Comment: Why not run 2 separate queries? It can be done in a single query but the value from group_concat will be returned a thousand (or a million) times, as many as the rows in table_a.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Which means the only way is using two different queries.

Comment: Wait, is your question really "how to return the value only once?" If yes, it's not clear from the question at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a single result set with the first row containing a list of all `user`s from `table_a`, and subsequent rows listing all `id`s from `table_b` (one per row), you could `UNION` the two queries. However, you would have to cast the results to a common data type (presumably something like `varchar`), and you would technically need to include a sort order field to guarantee that the users are in the first row.

```
SELECT values
FROM (select group_concat(user) as values, 1 as sort_order from table_b
      UNION ALL
      select CAST(id as varchar) as values, 2 as sort_order from table_a
     ) sq
ORDER BY sort_order
;
```

This will almost certainly be at least slightly slower than running the two queries separately. Not sure if that will matter, in your circumstance.

(Note:  `UNION` checks for and eliminates duplicate rows; `UNION ALL` just combines all rows without checking. Since we don't need to worry about duplicates....)

Comment: Preferably `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 8.0 you can do [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), so:

```
WITH subquery AS (SELECT group_concat(user) AS user FROM table_b)
  SELECT table_a.id, subquery.user FROM table_a, subquery;
```

Comment: It still has the same effect of the original query, giving each row the `concat` value.

Comment: @Matheo the subquery/CTE is executed/evaluated once in this case. The value is returned multiple times, as your original query.

Comment: You could also use a derived table: `SELECT table_a.id, subquery.user FROM table_a CROSS JOIN (SELECT group_concat(user) AS user FROM table_b) subquery;` Same results, and the subquery evaluated only once, as the CTE version in the answer.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ well, it seems as u said, two queries is better, also having multiple rows isn't better than a new query with a single one as i suppose.